# API call in react-redux with thunk not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-actions

when I submit an email and password it doesn't give any error.But as i can see the api call in loginUser(email,password) function is not working.but the email is correctly passed to the function.
As this function is not working ,after submitting values any of the actions are not dispatching.

here is my index.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
//import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {loginUser} from '../../actions/LoginActions'
export class Login extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props)

       this.state = {
        email:"",
        password:""  
       }
       this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this); 
   }

   handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    let {email,password} =this.state;        
    loginUser(email,password);


  }
    render() {
        let {isloginPending, isloginSuccess, isloginError} = this.props;
        console.log(isloginPending);

        return (
            <div>
                <form  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 

<formgroup>
<input
type="email"
value={this.state.email}
onChange={(event)=>{this.setState({ email: event.target.value })}}
placeholder="Email"
id="email"
required
/>
</formgroup>
<formgroup>
<input
type="password"
value={this.state.password}
type="password"
onChange={(event)=>{this.setState({ password: event.target.value })}}
placeholder="Password "
id="password"
required
/>
</formgroup>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
{ isloginPending && <div>Please wait...</div> }
{ isloginSuccess && <div>Success.</div> }
{ isloginError && <div>{isloginError.message}</div> }

</form> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
       // login: (email,password) => dispatch(loginUser(email,password))
         };
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return{
        isloginPending: state.loginR.isloginPending,
        isloginSuccess:state.loginR.isloginSuccess,
        isloginError:state.loginR.isloginError 
    }
}
export default connect (mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps) (Login);
```

here is my action.js file

```
import * as actionType from './ActionType';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

export function loginUser(email, password) {
  console.log(email);
  return dispatch => { 
      dispatch(loginBegin(true));
      dispatch(login(false));
      dispatch(loginError(null));

      fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3001/user/login",{
      method:'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
    UserEmail:email,
    Password:password,

      })},{withCredentials:'include'})
      .then (res=>res.json())
      .then (res=>{
        if(res.message==='Authorized'){
        console.log("authorized");
        dispatch(loginBegin(true));
        dispatch(login(false));

       /*
        this.setState({
            email : "",
            password : ""

          });
          */
          localStorage.setItem('sessionType', res.result.sessionType);
          localStorage.setItem("UserId" , res.result.UserId);
      }
    else{
      console.log("error");
    }
    })


    }
  }


export const loginBegin =(isloginPending) =>({
  type :actionType.LOGIN_BEGINS,
  payload:isloginPending
});

export const login =(isloginSuccess) =>({
  type :actionType.LOGIN_COMPLETE,
  payload:isloginSuccess
});

export const loginError =(isloginError) =>({
  type :actionType.LOGIN_ERROR,
  payload:isloginError
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dispatch the action in order to make it work since you are returning another function from within `loginUser`

You can do that with `mapDispatchToProps`

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
       login: (...args) => dispatch(loginUser(...args))
   };
}
```

and in component

```
handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    let {email,password} =this.state;        
    this.props.login(email,password);
}
```

Comment: then I get this error : Login.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.login is not a function

Comment: You seem to be using the unconnected Login component, remove export from before the class name `export class Login extends Component`  and import Login as a default import everywhere you are using it

Comment: Hey @ShubhamKhatri, How to handle the same situation with useDispatch hook?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    const{loginUser} = this.props;
    event.preventDefault();
    let {email,password} =this.state;        
    loginUser(email,password);
}
```

and in mapDispatchToProps

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        loginUser: (email,password) => dispatch(loginUser(email,password))
    };
}
```